# MYSQLjava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

Having trouble connecting to a mysql database in java. It used to work fine a couple of days ago and I'm not sure what happened.

The URL seems to be constructed correctly and I can access the db using adminer. I also added mysql-connector-java-5.1.33.jar to my debug configuration classpath in eclipse. Not sure what's wrong here.

```
private final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
private final String USR = "test";
private final String PWD = "***";
```

...

```
  try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USR, PWD);
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

            if (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("Ereur de connection MYSQL" + ex);
            //Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            //lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code seems like you have not loaded the Driver class and the exception says the same thing too. `No Suitable Driver`. You need to do the following, before trying to create a connection.

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`